# Gradient descent function with output plot and regression line

Tags: r, machine-learning

I've been running the following code which returns the correct coefficients. However, no matter where I put a `plot` call, I can't get any plot output.

I'm not sure if a reproducible example is needed here, as I think this can be solved by looking at my `gradientDescent` function below? It's my first attempt at running this algorithm in R:

```
gradientDescent <- function(x, y, learn_rate, conv_threshold, n, max_iter) {
  m <- runif(1, 0, 1)
  c <- runif(1, 0, 1)
  yhat <- m * x + c
  cost_error <- (1 / (n + 2)) * sum((y - yhat) ^ 2)
  converged = F
  iterations = 0
  while(converged == F) {
    m_new <- m - learn_rate * ((1 / n) * (sum((yhat - y) * x)))
    c_new <- c - learn_rate * ((1 / n) * (sum(yhat - y)))
    m <- m_new
    c <- c_new
    yhat <- m * x + c
    cost_error_new <- (1 / (n + 2)) * sum((y - yhat) ^ 2)
    if(cost_error - cost_error_new <= conv_threshold) {
      converged = T
    }
    iterations = iterations + 1
    if(iterations > max_iter) {
      converged = T
    return(paste("Optimal intercept:", c, "Optimal slope:", m))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A reproducible example is needed. The code you provided does not even show where or what you are trying to plot, so diagnosing is impossible.

Comment: I posted on the fly so didn't have time to put up the whole thing. I got it sorted in the end anyway. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you have been doing that was ineffective. The base graphics functions `plot` and `abline` should be able to produce output even when used inside functions. Lattice and ggplot2 graphics are based on `grid`-grpahics and would therefore need a `print()` wrapped around the function calls to create output (as described in the R-FAQ). So try this:

```
gradientDescent <- function(x, y, learn_rate, conv_threshold, n, max_iter) 
    { ## plot.new() perhaps not needed
      plot(x,y)
      m <- runif(1, 0, 1)
      c <- runif(1, 0, 1)
      yhat <- m * x + c
      cost_error <- (1 / (n + 2)) * sum((y - yhat) ^ 2)
      converged = F
      iterations = 0
      while(converged == F) {
        m_new <- m - learn_rate * ((1 / n) * (sum((yhat - y) * x)))
        c_new <- c - learn_rate * ((1 / n) * (sum(yhat - y)))
        m <- m_new
        c <- c_new
        yhat <- m * x + c
        cost_error_new <- (1 / (n + 2)) * sum((y - yhat) ^ 2)
        if(cost_error - cost_error_new <= conv_threshold) {
          converged = T
        }
        iterations = iterations + 1
        if(iterations > max_iter) { abline( c, m)  #calculated 
          dev.off()
          converged = T
        return(paste("Optimal intercept:", c, "Optimal slope:", m))
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Beautiful!! It works well. Initially, I was getting no plot with the regression line but once dev.off() is removed it works a treat. Thank you kindly sir.

Comment: In addition, the print wrapper around a ggplot call works perfectly to produce a variant of the above example. Thanks again.